# Why can we only measure the electromagnetism and gravitation in real life, and not the nuclear forces?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, standard-model, weak-interaction, strong-force

Why can we only measure the electromagnetism and gravitation in real life, and not the nuclear forces? All our senses are explained with EM forces and pressure values directly and heat transfer.

Comment: There are many things in the universe that we cannot directly sense? The goal of physics is not limited to explain the things we can sense.

Comment: Hiroshimans and Nagasakians disagree.

Comment: Because EM and gravity are long-ranged forces and the nuclear forces are microscopically short-ranged.

Comment: We don´t know where our counsciouness stay, a part of the brain, of course, and the concious part is from the same particles: protons, electrons, maybe neutrons. But these electrons and protons emits not only photons, also nuclear forces bosons. We are in interaction with it. The, why can´t we fell these emissions and absorptions, only from the photons?

Answer (score 3):

> Why can’t we in real life only the electromagnetism and gravitation and not the nuclear forces?

Because observations and measurements more than a hundreds years ago gave  numbers and observations that could not be explained with just electromagnetism and gravity.

Radiation alpha, beta, gamma are seen by our senses and affect our bodies after all.

At the same time other observations made inventing quantum mechanics inevitable: spectra of atoms, photoelectric effect, black body radiation.

The predictions of quantum mechanical models have lead to discovering fission, fusion, and elementary particles, all observable with  our senses  and fitted with the appropriate quantum mechanical models.

The atomic bomb surely was sensed by those unfortunate to be in Hiroshima and Nagasaki.

Answer (score 2):

We evolved in a particular environment (Earth's land surface) and at a particular size scale (about 1 meter). In this environment electromagnetic signals like light and IR travel far and fast, and objects are big enough that gravity matters to predicting their motion but is not entirely dominant. Sound and smells also provide useful information for survival.

We are insensitive to a lot of electromagnetism too (radio, polarisation, magnetic fields, IR, UV...). Some animals have survival needs making detecting some of them useful, whether this is because of different needs (long-range navigation) or a different size scale (tiny animals cannot see visible light sharply due to diffraction).

Suppose a mutant proto-human was able to detect the strong or weak force. What would they learn from this? All matter around us is full of strong force, and there is no real difference between a hungry tiger, a rock or air in this respect. Plus, the range is subatomic, so the mutant would not be able to notice anything not touching their sensors. Same thing for the weak force. So their mutation would not help with anything and not increase their evolutionary fitness.

What about radiation like gamma-rays or beta-particles? This would only give a survival advantage in environments where dangerous radiation were a thing. But outside a few very rare environments like natural nuclear reactors this would not give a survival advantage, only a cost of maintaining a sensory organ for it.

Answer (score 1):

> All our senses are explained with EM forces and pressure values directly and heat transfer.

**Wrong.**

At first I will begin, that there are some things whose existence you don't experience directly, but as soon as you remove that thing out of your reach - you begin to feel its absence. Take for example oxygen: you don't see it, you don't feel it generally, except as side-effect of wind you can say that you begin to feel an air flow. However air is not only composed of $\mathrm{O}_2$ molecules, there's nitrogen, argon and other gases. So it's still valid to say that even in an airflow, AKA wind, you don't feel oxygen directly. However just for a minute stop breathing, and your organism will start to feel that your blood is low on oxygen. Thus you feel oxygen absence very well, but not its existence directly.

Same for nuclear forces—we don't feel these forces directly, how they keep our organism's atoms in place. However if you've ever heard what happens to people when they are under high dosage of radio-active radiation—that feels terrific. For example people who worked under high radiation in [Chernobyl disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_disaster) or those who survived (temporarily) after [atomic bombings of Hiroshima and Nagasaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_bombings_of_Hiroshima_and_Nagasaki)—all those poor people have experienced [acute radiation syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_radiation_syndrome). This was an **exact** consequence of organism's atoms being ionized under radiation and in case of big intensity of gamma radiation—our organism's atoms nucleus are starting to break apart too, contributing to the same ARS illness. The point is same—**you don't feel strong force of your organism's atoms, however you feel when you begin losing it**, as in oxygen case.

Comment: But your senses doesn´t receive direct information for nuclear forces....Is simpy a biological evolution case? Maybe, but I was curious about that. I think, maybe not for a physicist, but it is a very curious situation for a biological, for example

Comment: Yes, no direct senses of nuclear forces, however you can't explain ARS disease otherwise as gamma radiation breaks your organism atom nucleus, because strong atomic force is not able to keep atom nucleus as a whole anymore. (Gamma radiation energy becomes bigger than your atoms nucleus binding energy.) And plus of course ionization effect, for which is lower threshold energy needed (compared to nucleus breaking). This is the only explanation possible, thus I denied your view that your ALL senses can be explained without atomic forces included.

Comment: As about "not full information about environment". No creature on Earth receives full information about surroundings and itself into nerve center. Primary reason can be because your brain will not be able to handle such information, there's gazillions of petabytes of information around and you would need a brain with size comparable of sun to process such information :-) Besides, most importantly- you don't need it for survival actually. That is - cost over benefits factor  is too high for such feature, thus nature doesn't bothers about it.